# How can I make a fixed width mutliline table in vim/neovim?

Tags: text, vim, neovim

I want to write a text file for a video script. I want to format the text like a table. It needs to have two columns and any number of rows.  I want the text in the 'cells' to be multiline but have a fixed width for the columns.

Here's the effect I'm trying to achieve with three columns.  I don't need the scene numbers:  [Example Script](https://inboundvideomarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/AV-script-3.gif)

VimWiki is the best I've found so far, but the columns aren't fixed width and it's difficult or impossible to re-flow the text.

Any suggestions for a better way to do this?

Comment: hacky partial solution: have one file per column. Open each file in a window vertically. Then `set scrollbind` on each window to lock the scrolling of the windows together. Use one hard line ends per "row". Then depend on vim soft wrapping long lines. Doesn't get you a single plain text file though. the cmd line utility `paste` would glue the lines together but not wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the markdown table style is suited for your demands. The example scripts can be found below. I use `vim-table-mode` to draw these tables, once the table has been created, you can add new rows to it with automatically match the previous width. Here is the [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lVQ0VJY3ps) for this plugin and its GitHub repo can be found [here](https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-table-mode).

```
| App                 | Usage            | NeedTimeMaster?   |
| ------------------- | ---------------  | ----------------- |
| Telegram            | tec. Chat        | No                |
| Mail                | Communications   | No                |
| Chrome              | Browser          | No                |
| Things              | Tasks            | Maybe(slightly)   |
| Books               | Books            | No                |
```

Comment: I looked at vim-table-mode but it lacks the essential multi-line cell feature.   There are several open issues on the github repo asking for exactly this so I'm not alone.